# How to export files from Visio 2010 to ASTAH Community file?

Tags: export, uml, visio

I'm having a little problem with a lot of uml diagrams, these were created using Visio 2010, but now we're using ASTAH Community for the diagrams and we want to take advantage of the diagrams on Visio.

recently we were try exporting using XPS format, and other methods where the file was exported on an image file, but this don't allow us to edit the diagrams.

Somebody know a way to export the Visio files to a astah file, keeping the editing function ?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No idea. Also who down-voted your question. I hate those trolls here on SO... Doesn't ASTAH have a forum?

Comment: ASTAH have an forum for the Community version, but don't have any answer for this question, i'm looking for other forums on visio or other software for export the diaagrams, thanks for your comment...